# Change column to shown format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to conver my fisrt data as second data. I need change column to shown format in Python. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't the resulting Df have a row for ```73652hd  hr  finance```?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a input dataframe of the form:

```
 passport n   position
0    23w72s1    finance
1    23w72s1         IT
2    3uus832        law
3    3uus832  help desk
4    3uus832         hr
5    75682hd         hr
6    75682hd    finance
7    75682hd         IT
8    75682hd  Team Lead
```

You can create a new dataframe as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def newdf(dfi):
    rslt = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(1, dfi.shape[0]):
        if dfi.iloc[i-1]['passport n'] == dfi.iloc[i]['passport n']:
            rslt['passport n'].append(df.iloc[i]['passport n'])
            rslt['past'].append(dfi.iloc[i-1]['position'])
            rslt['current'].append(dfi.iloc[i]['position'])
    return pd.DataFrame(rslt)
```

Using the above

```
newdf(df)
```

produces:

```
passport n  past    current
0   23w72s1 finance IT
1   3uus832 law help desk
2   3uus832 help desk   hr
3   75682hd hr  finance
4   75682hd finance IT
5   75682hd IT  Team Lead
```

Comment: it only shows bellow output :

 passport_n past current
0 75682hd hr finance
1 75682hd finance IT
2 75682hd IT Team Lead

Comment: Does your dataframe look like my example?:

Comment: yes,they completely the same

Comment: My code produces the output shown, not sure what you are doing differently